# Cannot access Windows after dual booting with Ubuntu on different drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I recently tried to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with my Windows 10, but I messed up the installation and now I can't access Windows 10. Please note that Ubuntu is on a different HDD than Windows.

I tried `update-grub`, but it didn't work and the boot-repair displays the following message:

> GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
>   Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

Any ideas on how to fix that?